# Styling checkboxes & radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, radio-button

I want to use an image for an unchecked checkbox and another image for a checked checkbox. I don't want to add labels, classes or anything like that. I want to leave the HTML alone, have it just display `<input type="checkbox" />` I don't mind using JavaScript or jQuery, as long as I can leave the HTML alone.
This is an example of what I'm looking for but it only works in Webkit browsers.
http://jsfiddle.net/7kScn/
Without adding labels, or classes or IDs, would there be a solution for this?

Comment: do you mind JavaScript appending classes after the page has loaded, so the HTML code is still bare in the source?

Comment: @SetSailMedia I was considering it, but I also want it to be more organic so it covered every checkbox and radio button...

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I must have not been clear, yes, there are very flexible and nice things you can do with jQuery, CSS (X)HTML and Whatever else... but in essence, they convert the `input` into a `div`. It was also hard to find something good for select drop downs. I ended up finding this for the select boxes and I am going to try to see if I can do something similar for checkboxes and radio buttons. http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

I just found something perfect. http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/imageless-css-3-custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/
Although the colors and font is pretty ugly, it accomplishes what I needed it to, plus those are easy to change.

Answer (score 1):

it might help to go for Jquery UI

Checkbox eg. http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

Radio eg. http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio

gl hf

Comment: i use jquery develop plugin so my javascript libraries develop themselves automatically. great comment. plus

Answer (score 0):

this looks like an interesting option, although it appears to be only in beta:

http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/

Answer (score 0):

Fun friday challenge, here's my somewhat hacky implementation. Keep in mind for a real app you'll have to include better input type targeting and more robust selectors:

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2RNVh/

```
$("input").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.hide();

    var $image = $("<img src='http://refundfx.com.au/uploads/image/checkbox_empty.png' />").insertAfter(this);    

    $image.bind("click", function() {
        var $checkbox = $(this).prev("input");
        $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));    
        checkImage();
    })

    function checkImage() {
        if($image.prev("input").prop("checked")) {
            $image.attr("src", "http://refundfx.com.au/uploads/image/checkbox_full.png");
        } else {
            $image.attr("src", "http://refundfx.com.au/uploads/image/checkbox_empty.png");
        }
    }

});
```